# HTML do not refresh common elements when switching pages

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if it would be possible to have common elements between pages that don't refresh when you change pages.

More specifically, what I mean is: I have a header that is common to several pages, and contains the links to the pages themselves. Only, whenever I click on the header, the whole page refreshes, with the typically annoying flickering that comes with it. I would like to know if it would be possible to have the header fixed between pages, so that when I click on a link to change page the content refreshes but the header doesn't. (The same goes for the background as well).

What I have right now is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#header").load("../header_footer/header.html");
  });
</script>
```

and in the body (common to all pages)

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to do this with just HTML or Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible to keep any page elements (or JS) when loading a new page. But you can use Ajax to load parts of a page without affecting other parts of a page - and *you are already doing that*. So other than the fact that you seem to have it backwards in that you're using Ajax to load the common header, what's the problem? (Or of course you can always go old-school and use iframes.)

Comment: This is possible just through ajax requests. There are a lot of javascript frameworks to help in this task. Take a look in [Sencha Ext Js](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible using traditional page loads. If you don't want the flickering, I'd recommend making your site a Single Page App. Basically, you'd be loading your page *once* in the browser, and then all subsequent pages are dynamically loaded into the DOM via Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#pg2,#pg3{display:none;}
</style>

<body>

<div id="header"><button onclick="page(1)">Page 1</button><button onclick="page(2)">Page 2</button><button onclick="page(3)">Page 3</button></div>
<div id="pg1">

</div>
<div id="pg2">

</div>
<div id="pg3">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var pg =new Array;
pg[1] = document.getElementById('pg1')
pg[2] = document.getElementById('pg2')
pg[3] = document.getElementById('pg3')
function page(p){
  pg[1].style.display='none'
  pg[2].style.display='none'
  pg[3].style.display='none'
  pg[p].style.display='block'

}

//]]>
```